# Elegant Array.multipick(?) implementation

Tags: algorithm, f#, functional-programming, ocaml

I'd like to implement something akin to imaginary `Array.multipick`:

```
Array.multipick : choosers:('a -> bool) [] -> array:'a [] -> 'a []
```

Internally, we test each array's element with all `choosers`, the first `chooser` to return `true` is removed from `choosers` array, and we add that `chooser`'s argument to the result. After that, we continue interation *while `choosers` array has elements left*.

The last part is important, because without early exit requirement this could be solved with just `Array.fold`.

This could be easily implemented with something like:

```
let rec impl currentIndex currentChoosers results
```

But it's too procedural for my taste. Maybe there's more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fold with an early exit is a good idea, however a production-worthy one specifically targeting arrays would need to be written in a fairly imperative manner. For simplicity, I'll grab the more general sequence one from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18903608/679898).

```
let multipick (choosers: ('a -> bool) array) (arr: 'a array) : 'a array =
    let indexed =
        choosers
        |> Seq.indexed
        |> Map.ofSeq
    ((indexed, []), arr)
    ||> foldWhile (fun (cs, res) e ->
        if Map.isEmpty cs then
            None
        else
            match cs |> Seq.tryFind (fun kvp -> kvp.Value e) with
            | Some kvp -> Some (Map.remove kvp.Key cs, e :: res)
            | None     -> Some (cs, res))
    |> snd
    |> List.rev
    |> Array.ofList
```

I'm using a `Map` keyed by array index to keep track of remaining functions - this allows for easy removal of elements, but still retains their order (since map key-value pairs are ordered by keys when iterating).

F# `Set` wouldn't work with functions due to comparison constraint. `System.Collections.Generic.HashSet` would work, but it's mutable, and I'm not sure if it would retain ordering.

Comment: yeah, I've had smth similar in mind! also lazy Seq.scan + Seq.takeWhile combination is pretty neat.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite difficult to write elegant code using arrays of changing size. Here is some code that works on lists instead and does not mutate any values.

```
let rec pick accum elem tried = function
    | [] -> (accum, List.rev tried)
    | chooser :: rest ->
        if chooser elem then (elem :: accum, List.rev_append tried rest)
        else pick accum elem (chooser :: tried) rest

let rec multipick_l accum choosers list =
    match choosers, list with
    | [], _
    | _, [] -> List.rev accum
    | _, elem :: elems ->
        let (accum', choosers') = pick accum elem [] choosers in
        multipick_l accum' choosers' elems

let multipick choosers array =
    Array.of_list
        (multipick_l [] (Array.to_list choosers) (Array.to_list array))
```

If you think that `Array.fold_left` is usable except for the early exit requirement, you can use an exception to exit early.

Comment: thank you for the answer! I'll try implementing something like `Set<'a -> bool>` for immutably keeping track of tried choosers later today, and then likely accept your answer :)